# When trying to reuse an HTTP connection to process the Keep-Alive header, recv is blocked by reading the second request from the client

Tags: c++, http, httpserver

Writing a small http server, I have to handle "Connection: keep-alive" header. Before that I used the standard request processing model: one connection is opened for one request, then processed, a response is sent, and then the connection is closed. But “Keep Alive” allows you to re-use the connection. The question is, how can I do that? What algorithm should I use?

I tried to do it like this: opening a connection using accept -> reading data from the client socket using recv -> processing a request -> sending a response using send. This loop continues until recv returns a value = 0, and on exiting the loop the connection is closed. But the problem is that on the second iteration of the loop, after processing the first request, recv is blocked. Please tell me at what step I was wrong.

```
    for(;;)
        {
          client *current = client::listen_port(cone.get_socket());//called here to accept
          httpHandler worker(current);//this class handles requests, we pass a pointer to the class object in it, which contains information about the client
          for(;;)
          {
              httpParser* temp = new httpParser(current->get_client());// recv is called and the httpParser class parses the request
              if (temp->get_recvByte() > 0)
                worker.handle(temp);//if recv returned something, we process the request and respond to it
              if (temp->get_recvByte() == 0)
                  break;
              if (temp->get_recvByte())
                  std::cout << "error";
              delete temp;
          }
        }
```

this constructor forms the header

```
   heading::heading(const int content_size, const std::string &file)
{
    head = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";

    std::string Content_Type, Content_Length;
    std::string extension = file.substr(file.find(".") + 1);

    if (extension == "png" || extension == "gif")
        Content_Type = "Content-Type: image/apng\r\n";
    else if(extension == "jpg")
        Content_Type = "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n";
    else
        Content_Type = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
    Content_Length = "Content-Lenght: " + std::to_string(content_size) + "\r\n";
    head = head + "Server: Cone \r\n" + Content_Type + Content_Length + "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
}
```

processing function

```
void httpHandler::handle(httpParser *temp)
{
    parser = temp;
    if (parser->get_type() == HEAD)
    {
        heading head;
        send(newclient->get_client(), head.get_head().c_str(), head.get_head().length(), 0);
        return;
    }
    if (parser->get_type() == UNKNOWN)
        send(newclient->get_client(), heading::error404().c_str(), heading::error404().length(), 0);

    if (!parser->get_dynamic())
        static_handle();

    else
        dynamic_handle();
    parser = nullptr;
}
```

static content processing

```
void httpHandler::static_handle()
{
    std::string buffer; 
    std::ifstream file(getenv("path") + parser->get_file(), std::ifstream::binary); 
    if (file)
     {
         auto const size{file.tellg()}; 
         file.seekg(0); 
         char current;
         buffer.reserve(size);
         while(file.get(current)) //читаем файл
             buffer.push_back(current);
         heading head(buffer.length(), parser->get_file());
         buffer = head.get_head() + buffer;  заголовок к буферу
         send(newclient->get_client(), buffer.c_str(), buffer.length(), 0); 
      }
      else
         send(newclient->get_client(), heading::error404().c_str(), heading::error404().length(), 0);

     file.close();
}
```

parser

```
httpParser::httpParser(int client_d)
{
    char buffer[req_buff_size];
    std::cout << "Calling recv() on socket " << client_d << std::endl;
    recvByte = recv(client_d, buffer,req_buff_size - 1, 0); // получаем сообщение из сокета
    if (recvByte > 0)
    {
        buffer[recvByte] = '\0';
        reqest = buffer;
        std::cout << reqest <<std::endl; // для тестов
        if (recvByte < 0)
           throw std::invalid_argument( "error recv\n" );

        if (reqest.find("GET") == 0)
        {
          type = GET;
          GET_parse();
        }
          else if (reqest.find("POST") == 0)
        {
          type = POST;
          POST_Parse();
        }
        else if (reqest.find("HEAD") == 0)
          type = HEAD;
        else
          throw std::invalid_argument( "invalid REQ\n" );

        requestedFile();
    }
}
```

connection closes in client destructor

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to assist you. As a guess, I would say that your server isn't responding with the appropriate connection keep-alive header either. But that's just a shot in the dark guess.

Comment: Your can't just read blindly, you need to actually parse the requests per the HTTP spec to know where one request ends and the next begins. And you need to look at the request headers to determine if the client even wants to use a keep alive or not. And also, keep alives have a timeout, you can't wait forever for a new request to arrive, eventually you have to close an idle connection

Comment: The loop should exit when `recv()` returns zero, not > 0, and you should always use a read timeout to defend against rogue clients, but younger a good knowledge of the HTTP RFCs to implement HTTP: more than is exhibited here.

Comment: @user207421 it's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
"Connection: keep-alive\n\n";
```

Should be:

```
"Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
```

Similarly, this doesn't look correct either with the forward slashes

```
"Server: Cone /r/n"
```

Should be:

```
"Server: Cone\r\n"
```

Comment: why \ r \ n? The response body begins after \ n \ n, in which case Connection: keep-alive last header

Comment: End of line markers in HTTP are `\r\n`.  The response body begins after two pairs of `\r\n`. I suspect most client parsers are forgiving if this seems to work today.  Also, most clients are going to expect a Content-Length header.

Comment: The best tool to debug HTTP issues between client and server is Fiddler.  Go get that.

Comment: This did not work, I corrected what you said and added the Content-Length processing.

Comment: recv blocks anyway

Comment: And you are sure the client is sending a connection:keep-alive header as well, right?

Comment: You'll need to provide a [mcve] for any more assistance.